# Optimizing a forum query

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

Can you guys help me optimize this query.  What's a more efficient way to do this?

```
SELECT *, ( 
         SELECT COUNT(id) FROM post WHERE created > 1288953377 AND topic_id = topic.id
    ) AS post_today FROM topic
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is what you need,

```
SELECT Col1,Col2,Col3, Count(id) from Topic 
LEFT JOIN post on topic_id = topic.id
where created > 1288953377
group by id,Col1,Col2,Col3
```

Comment: That's not the same. You lose all topics that had no post today. You want to use _LEFT JOIN_ instead of an _INNER JOIN_.

Comment: You are right. Left join makes more sense here. Edited my answer.